# Apple UDID Give Any Access?

Tags: ios, xcode, udid

I was having an issue with 'Archiving' my Xcode because my iOS device wasn't functioning.
A colleague has offered to provide his UDID / serial for his iOS device to allow me to archive my project.

Is this safe?
Does this compromise my account safety?
Does it give any of my information over to him?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a device to archive an app. Choose "Gereric iOS Device" from the device dropdown list:

[image]

Comment: no to have the provisioning profile, you need to attach an actual iOS device - well at least on the developer accounts

Comment: I did this very often. Probably I misunderstood "archive" in your context.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing this allows is the ability to install the app onto his device. Once the app is on his device, if he has the skill, he can extract any license keys and even reverse engineer portions of your app.

That said, these are all things that any user who has your app can do if you haven't guarded against such abuse.

Comment: I've just disabled his device then, can I ask - though it doesn't;t let me delete from my account - now that I've disabled it, does he still have the same permissions? And as for my Xcode project, I've archived it but haven't uploaded it to iTunes connect, is that okay too even though i disabled the device?

Comment: If the app is on his device, he can do anything to the app that anybody else could do if the app was on their device. Including the above things I mentioned. "Disabling" his device merely means he won't be able to install future versions of your app (except he could still submit a version that is posted to the App Store or created through an Enterprise account.)